# The implications of twelver /ithna Ashari belief that fadak was gift /endowment to fatima?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, shiism, shia-sunni, inheritance, fatima-zahra

I recently learnt that fadak was an endowment to fatima by the prophet of Islam and abu bakr confiscated it as per twelver

Fadak came under prophet/muslims in 628 CE.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conquest_of_Fadak
Zaynab bint Muhammad died in 629 CE.
Umm kulsum bint Muhammad died in 630 CE.

Twelver say fadak was endowment and not inheritance.
Even if it's assumed if this is endowment are we accepting that prophet did injustice to zaynab and umm kulthum by not gifting them anything? Is this a slander on the prophet of Islam?

I believe quran orders the parents to be just and equal in giving gifts to children.

Comment: `I believe quran orders the parents to be just and equal in giving gifts to children.` You should first prove this statement of yours, then post your question. AFAK, Islam does not obligate parents to gift the rest of their children if they decide to gift only one of them.

Comment: What I meant is you should first prove your claim `I believe quran orders the parents to be just and equal in giving gifts to children`. Because Islam does not obligate parents to gift the rest of their children if they decide to gift only one of them, AFAIK. If you do not prove then it means you are blaming the Prophet SAW in injustice towards his children. Do you realize that?

Comment: @Muslim Quran 4:135 and Al-Bukhari and Muslim and others, that the Prophet, sallallaahu ‘alayhi wa salam, said to Basheer who came to make him (i.e., the Prophet ) witness to a gift that he wanted to give his son, An-Nu‘maan : "O Basheer! Do you have children other than this (An-Nu‘maan)?” He answered in the affirmative. He further asked: "Have you given all of them the like of that (you intend to give to An-Nu‘maan)?” He answered in the negative. Thereupon the Prophet, sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam, said: “Then, do not make me witness, for I can never be a witness to injustice."

Comment: Will you clarify your question or not? You claim `I believe quran orders` but what you are quoting is Hadith narration. Quran 4:135 is about `Witnessing`. Not about gifting or inheritance.

Comment: @Muslim, Quran 16:90

Answer (score 0):

In Shiite thought, no woman is equal to the greatness and status of Hazrat Fatima, peace be upon her, and she is not equal to anyone, not even her sisters, and it is not strange that Fadak was given to her.
Ali Ibn Abi Talib also instructed his son Abbas to respect and take care of his other son Hussein (as) (eventually Abbas was sacrificed to Hussein)
From which verse did you deduce that all the children of the prophets are equal? Have you not read the story of Prophet Jacob and his son Joseph?

Comment: Which verse says shes superior to all women. Instead Mary was chosen above women of all nation.face value this verse tells Mary better than fatima

Comment: Have you read the commentaries under this verse?
The meaning of Maryam is her superiority over the women of her time
  - Abd al-Rahman bin Jozi, Zadal al-Masir, vol. 1, p. 315.
- Jalal al-Din Siyuti, Alder al-Manthor, vol. 2, p. 194;
-Ismail Bin Kathir Damaschi, Tafsir al-Qur'an al-Azeem, vol. 2, p. 647.
- Mahmoud Alousi, Ruh al-Ma'ani, vol. 3, p. 138;
- Ali Khazen, Tafsir al-Khazen, vol. 1, p. 244;
- Hasan Basri, Tafsir al-Hasan al-Basri, vol. 1, p. 212;
- Atiq bin Mohammad Sourabadi, Tafsir Sourabadi, Vol. 1, p. 281

Comment: In Sahih al-Bukhari, Book of Beginning of Creation, according to Aisha, the Messenger of God said to his daughter: Are you not satisfied to be the mistress of the women of Paradise or the women of faith?

Comment: @s.mostafa.b, you need to support your claims with evidences. You can use [this](https://alhabib.org/en/how-can-fatima-peace-be-upon-her-own-the-right-of-fadak-while-women-do-not-inherit-according-to-the-shi%ca%bbah/) as a help. If you understand Arabic then also take a look at Shia tafseer of verses 8:1, 59:6-7.

Comment: @s.mostafa.b, where does it say Fatima is the best of all women from eve to last? Ibn kathir said khadijah is best women of this nation based on a hadith